# Есть ли способ воспроизвести звук сразу при открытии ссылки сайта?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, аудио

1. При входе на сайт создаётся элемент 
   `greetings = document.createElement("audio");
   greetings.src = "sounds/greetings.mp3";`
2. Потом в звук включается в `window.onload`. `window.onload() { greeting.play(); }`
3. Выскакивает ошибка: `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.`

Как бороться?

- Пробовал задавать `onfocus` на `window` - не помогло.
- Пробовал 
  `greetings.pause(); greetings.currentTime = 0; greetings.play();` - не помогло.
- Пробовал совмещать первый и второй способ - не помогло.
- От безысходности пробовал:

  ```
  var greetingsStatus = setInterval(function() {
      try {
          greeting.play();
          clearInterval(greetingsStatus);
          greetingsStatus = null;
      } catch(e) {
          console.log(e);
      }
  }, 200);
  ```

Ошибка также: `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.`

Люди добрые, помогите: что сделать, что бы звук играл сразу после открытия страницы? Даже если она открыта через `ctrl` или колёсико мыши. (Пользователь еще не зашёл на страницу, но звук уже играет).

P.S Google Chrome Версия 66.0.3359.139 (Официальная сборка), (64 бит)

P.S.3 Пока выбирал метки для вопроса: всплыла подсказка: web-audio. Это о audio API. Я его пока не знаю. Может знает кто: будет ли с ним мою задачу проще решить?

---

Ошибка возникает только при запуске сайта на локальном сервере. При переходе с сайта **stack overflow** на мой сайт всё работает отлично. Объясните тогда, как так устроен chrome, что сайтам, запущенным с локального сервера chrome не доверяет, а сайтам в интернете - очень даже.

Если у вас другой браузер, или chrome другой версии, и у вас не включается звук или появляется ошибка в консоли - отпишитесь.

Comment: У вас такой код не будет также работать в Сафари. Это своеобразная защита, что бы звук не играл до дех пор, пока пользователь не сделает страницу активной. Web-audio поможет в хроме, но не поможет в Сафари.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko ошибка появляется только при запуске с локального сервера. Если перейти на сайт, который на хостинге, ошибка не возникает. Странно, что браузер не доверяет сайтам, запущенным с локального сервера, а сайтам в интернете - доверяет. [здесь](http://playcaz.xyz)

Comment: Нет, не доверяет. http://prntscr.com/jepb6u

Comment: Большинство пользователей сразу закрывает подобные шумящие вкладки, подумайте, действительно ли это то, что вам нужно.

Comment: Здесь, кстати, вполне хорошо описано, почему так, зачем так и как надо https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: @vp_arth там короткая реплика (2-3 сек), громкость которой изначально выставлена на 50%

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Спасибо за статью. Судя по всему у меня работает только потому, что я часто захожу на этот домен.

Comment: Сталкивался с такой проблемой много раз, в статье все написано, по практике встречал несколько сайтов которые как то обходили запрет на воспроизведение аудио на сайте. Но политика такая, что пока пользователь не разрешит (сознательно или нет) то звук нельзя воспроизводить, та же ситуация с video autoplay если нет атрибута muted то автоплей не будет играть

Answer (score 2):

Звуки не будут автовоспроизводиться, пока пользователь не взаимодействует со страницей.
Сделайте так чтобы пользователь захотел щелкнуть по странице в скором времени после того как зашел на сайт. Например во Вконтакте сложно долго не взаимодействовать.
И когда щелкнет первый раз, можете сразу воспроизвести звук (при необходимости конечно)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте jQuery trigger.
К примеру у вас есть 2 кнопки на сайте play и pause. можно сделать так чтобы при загрузки страницы в хроме сымитировался клик на кнопку play

Вот HTML:

```html
<div class="musicPlayer">
    <audio class="listen" preload="none" data-size="50" src="music_url" id="audio0"></audio>
    <button class="playerButtons playMusic"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></button>
    <button class="playerButtons pauseMusic"><i class="fas fa-pause"></i></button>
</div>
```

Вот jS

```
$(window).on('load', function(){

    $(".playMusic").trigger('click');

})
```

Comment: лично мне это не помогло

Comment: @ВиталийФесюра Всё зависит от браузера. Если браузер запретил по умолчанию включение, то скрипт вам не поможет.

Comment: Это уже давно не работает с аудио. Запуск аудио возможен только после действий пользователя

Answer (score 0):

Установите вашему тегу audio атрибут autoplay:

```
    greetings = document.createElement("audio");
    greetings.src = "sounds/greetings.mp3";
    greetings.autoplay = true;
```

и не забудьте вставить этот элемент в html.
Подробнее о атрибуте: http://htmlbook.ru/html/audio/autoplay

Comment: Уже давно [не работает](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)

Answer (score 0):

```
HTML:
    <body id="body">
    <a href="ваша ссылка" id="link">страница</a>
    </body>
```

JavaScript:

```
    document.querySelector("#link").onclick = () => {
      setTimeout(function () {
      let audio = 
      document.createElement("audio");
      audio.src = "твой аудио";
 
    document.querySelector("#body").appendChild(audio)
       audio.play();
    }, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]